# I cannot execute this embedded SQL statement in QUERY executer

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

When I put the `Select benefitid from tr_benefittype where fiscal = '1'` clause into the query executer in MSSQL it says that there is not a column of that name. I search the database and find that indeed there is no column named `benefitid` within the `tr_benefittype` table.  Is this column name being changed in some way before sending to the database?

Here is the JAVA code;

```
            m_risks = new TRRiskSet();
            new TRRiskSQL().getRisks(m_con, m_risks, m_currObject.getClass().getName(), 
                    m_currObject.getKey(), new String[] {"riskflag = 'R'"});

            budSQL.getBudgets(m_con, m_budgets, m_currObject.getClass().getName(), m_currObject.getKey(), 
                                            new String[] {"currencyid = " + corpCurrencyID});
            benSQL.getBenefits(m_con, m_benefits, m_currObject.getClass().getName(), m_currObject.getKey(), 
                    new String[] {"currencyid = " + corpCurrencyID + 
                " and benefitid in (select benefitid from tr_benefittype where fiscal='1')"});
            resSQL.getResourceBudgets(m_con, m_resources, m_currObject.getClass().getName(), 
                                                            m_currObject.getKey(), null);
```

I really just want to know if the java code is changing the SQL Query before it sends it to the database so that it really isn't calling the column that is apparent, benefitid"

Comment: I do not realy understand you question? why you are not change your sql with the correct column name?

Comment: I really just want to know if the java code is changing the SQL Query before it sends it to the database so that it really isn't calling the column that is apparent, benefitid"

Comment: no java doesn't change it, why would java do that? please share the error that MSSQL is returning...